# Writing to a floating point OpenGL texture in CUDA via a surface

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda, interop, textures

I'm writing an OpenGL/CUDA (6.5) interop application. I get a compile time error trying to write a floating point value to an OpenGL texture through a surface reference in my CUDA kernel.

Here I give a high level description of how I set up the interop, but I am successfully reading from my texture in my CUDA kernel, so I believe this is done correctly. I have an OpenGL texture declared with

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0, GL_RGB32F_ARB, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

After creating the texture I call `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage` with `cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsSurfaceLoadStore` set. Before running my CUDA kernel, I unbind the texture and call `cudaGraphicsMapResources` on the `cudaGraphicsResource` pointers obtained from `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage`. Then I get a `cudaArray` from `cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray`, create an appropriate resource descriptor for the array, and call `cudaCreateSurfaceObject` to get a pointer to a `cudaSurfaceObject_t`. I then call `cudaMemcpy` with `cudaMemcpyHostToDevice` to copy the `cudaSurfaceObject_t` to a buffer on the device allocated by `cudaMalloc`.

In my CUDA kernel I can read from the surface reference with something like this, and I have verified that this works as expected.

```
__global__ void cudaKernel(cudaSurfaceObject_t tex) {
    int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    float4 sample = surf2Dread<float4>(tex, (int)sizeof(float4)*x, y, cudaBoundaryModeClamp);
```

In the kernel I want to modify sample and write it back to the texture. The GPU has compute capability 5.0, so this should be possible. I am trying this

```
surf2Dwrite<float4>(sample, tex, (int)sizeof(float4)*x, y, cudaBoundaryModeClamp);
```

But I get the error:

```
error: no instance of overloaded function "surf2Dwrite" matches the argument list
argument types are: (float4, cudaSurfaceObject_t, int, int, cudaSurfaceBoundaryMode)
```

I can see in

```
cuda-6.5/include/surface_functions.h
```

that there are only prototypes for integral versions of `surf2Dwrite` that accept a `void *` for the second argument. I do see prototypes for `surf2Dwrite` which accept a `float4` with a templated `surface` object, However, I'm not sure how I could declare a templated `surface` object with OpenGL interop. I haven't been able to find anything else on how to do this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `GL_RGB` is not supported by `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage`, but you're reading with `float4` anyways, so i'm assuming a typo here.

Comment: That's not a typo, that's how it is being initialized. Maybe you're thinking that is the internal format. The internal format is `GL_RGB32F_ARB`. (See the `glTexImage2D` man page.) The format being `GL_RGB` asks opengl to treat the first float as R, second G, and third B.The fourth is ignored when rendering into the texture from OpenGL, as far as I understand.

Comment: The docu says that `GL_RGB32F` is not allowed. http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__OPENGL.html#group__CUDART__OPENGL_1gd7be3ca8a7a739d57f0b558562c5706e

Comment: Interesting. Well, in practice it seems to just ignore the alpha channel.

Comment: Maybe they fixed it in 6.5, but in 5.5 using RGB gives a Seg-Fault. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the answer was pretty simple, though I don't know why it works. Instead of calling

```
surf2Dwrite<float4>(sample, tex, (int)sizeof(float4)*x, y, cudaBoundaryModeClamp);
```

I needed to call

```
surf2Dwrite(sample, tex, (int)sizeof(float4)*x, y, cudaBoundaryModeClamp);
```

To be honest I'm not sure I fully understand CUDA's use of templating in c++. Anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

From the [CUDA Documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#surface-functions), here is the definition of surface template functions:

```
template<class T>
T surf2Dread(cudaSurfaceObject_t surfObj,
              int x, int y,
              boundaryMode = cudaBoundaryModeTrap);

template<class T>
void surf2Dread(T* data,
                 cudaSurfaceObject_t surfObj,
                 int x, int y,
                 boundaryMode = cudaBoundaryModeTrap);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a complete example of CUDA writing to a surface that's linked to an OpenGL texture, refer to this project:

https://github.com/nvpro-samples/gl_cuda_interop_pingpong_st

Comment: That's not a very useful answer for this problem because 1) your example uses the CUDA Driver API, and I was asking about the Runtime API, 2) your example uses the older surface references rather than newer surface objects in my question. It's not like there is just one accepted way to do this. Since the conclusion is simply "don't use the template notation with `surf2Dwrite`", asking people to dig through an entire git project to come to the same conclusion that was posted five months ago in the accepted answer also isn't super helpful...